# No permission on dvdrw station, wrong mounting point?

Tags: mount, dvd

tried burning an audio cd through a .cue file but no cigar. For some reason beyond my understanding the dvdrw is mounted at ~/mnt/dvdrw. Not knowing if that is the right place I found that I have no permissions whatsoever to use the device. I don't burn that much, but sometimes folks want an old fashioned cd and I would like to help them out.
What can be done about this, anyone? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: "no cigar" is a useless description of the error. Was there an error message? How did you "tried burning an audio CD through a `.cue` file"? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/dvdrw"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

To see how it's mounted, `grep dvdrw /etc/fstab /etc/mtab`. `/etc/fstab` is how we tell the system to mount filesystems, `/etc/mtab` is a system-generated file describing what is mounted at the current time.